# Why isn't Mac sed isn't matching what I expect?

Tags: regex, sed

`echo 'iPhone 12 Pro Max (5EF5105C-7EED-4017-979C-A6185E927B84) (Booted)' | sed -En 's,(\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+),\1,p'`

Because I'm using extended regex `-E (-r in GNU sed)` and -n for print only matched/replaced. Assuming my [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kURcw7/1) is correct,
expecting `5EF5105C-7EED-4017-979C-A6185E927B84` in the output, but getting **empty**.

Comment: Does it support `\w`? Try replacing `\w` with `[[:alnum:]_]`

Comment: note that your sed attempt will not change the line, because you are replacing with whatever was matched.. `\w` is most likely specific to GNU sed only... grep is better suited here if `-o` option is supported in mac version of grep (but that might still not support `\w`)... also,  please don't use regex101 for cli tools, the feature difference is too much

Comment: depending on your rest of the input data, you might be able to use something like `awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the serial number out from inside the parens, and you're not actually modifying anything, then use `grep`

```
$ echo 'iPhone 12 Pro Max (5EF5105C-7EED-4017-979C-A6185E927B84) (Booted)' \
    | grep -E  '\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+-\w+' -o

5EF5105C-7EED-4017-979C-A6185E927B84
```

`-o` tells grep "Just output what matched, not the entire line".

Comment: Indeed, `grep` is better for printing matching text and `BSD grep` does support `\w` unlike `BSD sed`